# Meaning and usage of Je?

Tags: preposition, adverb

**"Je" means each, and it can be adverb or preposition, which one is correct?**

1- "Insgesamt sind von 100 Frauen je, 12 Ausländerinnen und 54 deutsche Frauen müde."

2- "Insgesamt sind von je 100 Frauen, 12 Ausländerinnen und 54 deutsche Frauen müde."

3- "Insgesamt sind je 100 Frauen, 12 Ausländerinnen und 54 deutsche Frauen müde."

4- "Insgesamt sind per 100 Frauen, 12 Ausländerinnen von je und 54 deutsche Frauen von je müde."

5- "Insgesamt sind von 100 Frauen, 12 Ausländerinnen und 54 deutsche Frauen müde."

Comment: (2) and (3) are as I know (and say) it, while (1) seems "completely wrong/alien" to me. (3) is a casually shortened form of (2) and might be wrong due to Duden etc, but I think it is usable in daily talk and normal level essays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the english word for "je" in this context would come closer to "respectively".

You basically say "Over all, of 100 women, there are 12 foreighn and 54 german women tired respecively.

And I think the correct sentence would then be 1, but without the comma.

If instead you want to say "For every 100 women, there are 12 foreighn and 54 german women who are tired"

Then you would take 2. So context matters.

That being said, 3, 4 are grammatically wrong regardless of context.

5. Basically says the same thing as 2.

Answer (score 2):

That kinda depends on the context. Like some of these imply that you asked exactly 100 women whether they were tired and some imply that you made a much greater inquiry and for every 100 women that you've asked you've got the distribution (so more of a statistical average). 1 and 5 would be the first and 2-4 would be the second interpretation. 4 is also completely grammatically wrong as the construct "von je ..." implies that the sentence should continue here with a quantity but simply doesn't. Also you'd probably use pro instead of per in that case.

In that context "je" means something like ["for each invidiual person or thing"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/je_pro) so "je 100 Frauen, sind 66 von ihnen müde.

Also the sentence structure in general is kinda weird. I mean in English it would be "In total there are out of 100 women, 12 foreigners and 54 German citizens tired." Like each of these clauses is missing crucial parts.

Answer (score 2):

The word "je" has three distinct meanings, and even more translations, depending on context.

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/je) differs between:

1. in questions or statements: zu irgendeiner Zeit, jemals
   English: at any time at all, somewhen, ever

> Hast Du das je gesehen? --> Have you ever seen that (at all)?

> Für keinen Angriffskrieg kann es je ausreichend Grund gegeben. -->
> For no offensive war can (there) ever be sufficient reason.

2. distributive: jeweils
   English: (for) each, per, a, every ... there might be others for many different more or less fixed phrases. This is the case for the sentence in the question:

> Insgesamt sind von je 100 Frauen, 12 Ausländerinnen und 54 deutsche Frauen müde. --> For every 100 women, 12 are foreign and 54 German women are tired.

> Von je 100 verkauften Äpfeln stammen 34 aus dem Alten Land --> From every 100 apples sold, 34 originate from the 'Altes Land'

> Das Einkommen beträgt durchschnittlich 34000€ je Kopf. --> The income is 34000€ per capita on average.

> Je nach Testergebnis muss der Schüler die Stufe wiederholen. --> Depending on test result, the pupil has to repeat the year.

> Das Pferd wird im Rennen Zweiter oder Dritter, je nachdem, welche Form es hat. --> The horse will finish as 2nd or 3rd, depending on its form.

3. comparison: je… [desto]…, je… [umso]…, oder je…, je… (zeigt mit zwei Komparativen das gleichgerichtete Wachstum des zweiten Komparativ zum ersten an)
   English: the ... the ...

> Je länger ich auf sie einredete, desto stärker wurde ihr Unwille. --> The longer I talked to her, the stronger her reluctance got.

> Je länger ich das Bild betrachtete, umso deutlicher wurde mir seine Ästhetik. --> The longer I looked at the picture, the clearer its astetics became apparent to me.